# pdflatex in TexLive doesn't work for beamer style

Tags: beamer, pdftex, texlive

pdflatex -v

returns:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.28; using libpng 1.6.28
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.48.0
```

For this version of TexLive, its pdflatex doesn't work on my files using "beamer" style for generating presentations for unknown reasons. In brief, I'm getting an endless list of errors "Non-PDF special ignored!" and a pdf output is generated with only black pages.

Yet I can compile the files without any problem on other platforms
or going through a sequence latex, dvips, ps2pdf.

Many thanks in advance for any hint how to solve the above issue!

Alex

PS: The log file for a small test file:

```latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.9.26)  26 JUN 2019 07:59
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mysld
(./mysld.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2017/01/22 v3.40 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count79
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count80
\c@beamerpauses=\count81

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count82
\beamer@minimum=\count83
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box27
\beamer@modecount=\count84
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
\headheight=\dimen102
\headdp=\dimen103
\footheight=\dimen104
\sidebarheight=\dimen105
\beamer@tempdim=\dimen106
\beamer@finalheight=\dimen107
\beamer@animht=\dimen108
\beamer@animdp=\dimen109
\beamer@animwd=\dimen110
\beamer@leftmargin=\dimen111
\beamer@rightmargin=\dimen112
\beamer@leftsidebar=\dimen113
\beamer@rightsidebar=\dimen114
\beamer@boxsize=\dimen115
\beamer@vboxoffset=\dimen116
\beamer@descdefault=\dimen117
\beamer@descriptionwidth=\dimen118
\beamer@lastskip=\skip41
\beamer@areabox=\box28
\beamer@animcurrent=\box29
\beamer@animshowbox=\box30
\beamer@sectionbox=\box31
\beamer@logobox=\box32
\beamer@linebox=\box33
\beamer@sectioncount=\count85
\beamer@subsubsectionmax=\count86
\beamer@subsectionmax=\count87
\beamer@sectionmax=\count88
\beamer@totalheads=\count89
\beamer@headcounter=\count90
\beamer@partstartpage=\count91
\beamer@sectionstartpage=\count92
\beamer@subsectionstartpage=\count93
\beamer@animationtempa=\count94
\beamer@animationtempb=\count95
\beamer@xpos=\count96
\beamer@ypos=\count97
\beamer@showpartnumber=\count98
\beamer@currentsubsection=\count99
\beamer@coveringdepth=\count100
\beamer@sectionadjust=\count101
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=\count102

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(./keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\beamer@paperwidth=\skip42
\beamer@paperheight=\skip43
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count103
\Gm@cntv=\count104
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count105
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen119
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen120
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen121
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen122
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen123
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen124
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen125
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen126
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(./graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1996/10/31 v1.0c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (./graphics.sty
Package: graphics 1996/10/31 v1.0c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (./trig.sty
Package: trig 1994/10/16 v1.08 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (./graphics.cfg)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 82.
 (./dvips.def
File: dvips.def 1996/12/12 v3.0d Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen127
\Gin@req@width=\dimen128
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen129
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen130

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box34
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen131
\pgf@y=\dimen132
\pgf@xa=\dimen133
\pgf@ya=\dimen134
\pgf@xb=\dimen135
\pgf@yb=\dimen136
\pgf@xc=\dimen137
\pgf@yc=\dimen138
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count106
\c@pgf@countb=\count107
\c@pgf@countc=\count108
\c@pgf@countd=\count109
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvips.def

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postsc
ript.def
File: pgfsys-common-postscript.def 2008/10/01  (rcs-revision 1.22)
\pgf@objectcount=\count110
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count111
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count112
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 (./color.cfg)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen139
\pgfmath@count=\count113
\pgfmath@box=\box35
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count114
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen140
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen141
\pgf@picminy=\dimen142
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen143
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen144
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen145
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen146
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen147
\pgf@xx=\dimen148
\pgf@xy=\dimen149
\pgf@yx=\dimen150
\pgf@yy=\dimen151
\pgf@zx=\dimen152
\pgf@zy=\dimen153
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen154
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen155
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen156
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen157
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box36
\pgf@hbox=\box37
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box38
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count115
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen158
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen159
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen160
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen161
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen162
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen163
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count116
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box39
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count117
\XC@countmixins=\count118
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `atbegshi' (already loaded).
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen164
\Hy@linkcounter=\count119
\Hy@pagecounter=\count120

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count121

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4362.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4362.
Package hyperref Info: Option `implicit' set `false' on input line 4362.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4486.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4491.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4494.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4501.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode OFF; no redefinition of LaTeX internals.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4735.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count122

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5088.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen165
\Fld@menulength=\count123
\Field@Width=\dimen166
\Fld@charsize=\dimen167
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6342.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6350.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6357.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6372.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6412.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6416.
\Hy@abspage=\count124


Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count125
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count126

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks26
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
Package: sansmathaccent 2013/03/28

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
Package: translator 2010/06/12 ver 1.10

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-
mappings.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty
\beamer@argscount=\count127
\beamer@lastskipcover=\skip44
\beamer@trivlistdepth=\count128
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty
\c@lecture=\count129
\c@part=\count130
\c@section=\count131
\c@subsection=\count132
\c@subsubsection=\count133
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty
\beamer@framebox=\box40
\beamer@frametitlebox=\box41
\beamer@zoombox=\box42
\beamer@zoomcount=\count134
\beamer@zoomframecount=\count135
\beamer@frametextheight=\dimen168
\c@subsectionslide=\count136
\beamer@frametopskip=\skip45
\beamer@framebottomskip=\skip46
\beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\skip47
\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\skip48
\beamer@envbody=\toks27
\framewidth=\dimen169
\c@framenumber=\count137
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty
\beamer@verbatimfileout=\write4
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty
\beamer@splitbox=\box43
\beamer@autobreakcount=\count138
\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\dimen170
\beamer@frametitletoks=\toks28
\beamer@framesubtitletoks=\toks29
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.sty
\beamer@footins=\box44
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty
\beamer@frameboxcopy=\box45
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
\beamer@sbttoks=\toks30

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty
\bmb@box=\box46
\bmb@colorbox=\box47
\bmb@boxshadow=\box48
\bmb@boxshadowball=\box49
\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\box50
\bmb@temp=\dimen171
\bmb@dima=\dimen172
\bmb@dimb=\dimen173
\bmb@prevheight=\dimen174
)
\beamer@blockheadheight=\dimen175
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks31
)
\c@figure=\count139
\c@table=\count140
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty
\beamer@section@min@dim=\dimen176
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\ex@=\dimen177
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen178
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count141
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count142
\leftroot@=\count143
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count144
\DOTSCASE@=\count145
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
\big@size=\dimen179
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count146
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count147
\dotsspace@=\muskip11
\c@parentequation=\count148
\dspbrk@lvl=\count149
\tag@help=\toks33
\row@=\count150
\column@=\count151
\maxfields@=\count152
\andhelp@=\toks34
\eqnshift@=\dimen180
\alignsep@=\dimen181
\tagshift@=\dimen182
\tagwidth@=\dimen183
\totwidth@=\dimen184
\lineht@=\dimen185
\@envbody=\toks35
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks36
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2015/03/04 v2.20.2
\thm@style=\toks37
\thm@bodyfont=\toks38
\thm@headfont=\toks39
\thm@notefont=\toks40
\thm@headpunct=\toks41
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks42
)
\c@theorem=\count153
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemedefault
.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthemedefa
ult.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorthemede
fault.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemede
fault.sty
\beamer@dima=\dimen186
\beamer@dimb=\dimen187
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemede
fault.sty))) (./mysld.aux)
\openout1 = `mysld.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 2.

(./mysld.out) (./mysld.out)
\@outlinefile=\write5
\openout5 = `mysld.out'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmss/bx/n on input line 2.
\symnumbers=\mathgroup6
\sympureletters=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'

! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \slide
          {My slide}
? 

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 4.

[1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
\openout7 = `mysld.toc'.

\tf@snm=\write8
\openout8 = `mysld.snm'.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 4.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 4.
 (./mysld.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 4.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 4.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `mysld.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.


LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 16089 strings out of 493013
 306202 string characters out of 6135682
 383366 words of memory out of 5000000
 19286 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4845 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 56i,14n,55p,783b,549s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb>
Output written on mysld.pdf (1 page, 10080 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 38 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 33 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 3 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: your document is loading something that works only with latex + dvips, but as you don't show your code, one can't tell you what ...

Comment: The smallest beamer document would be something like `\documentclass{beamer} \begin{document} \slide{My slide} \end{document}`.  Are you able to compile that on other platforms?  Do you get the log file you've shown above?

Comment: For this toy beamer file I'm getting black screen pdf too:-(( A small excerpt from its log file is: Non-PDF special ignored!..
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 4.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 4.
 (./mysld.aux)

Comment: Then show the complete log-file of the small document.

Comment: I would like to, but there is a limit of ca 600 characters for my response that is not enough for my log file:-((

Comment: This is only another part of it: %&-line parsing enabled.
**mysld
(./mysld.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2017/01/22 v3.40 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count79
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count80

Comment: You can edit the question to add the log-file, no need to use the comments (but your system looks rather old ...)

Comment: check the log is not including dvips.def

Comment: I had to shorten a bit the log file because of: "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 38941."

Comment: FYI: 
Package: trig 1994/10/16 v1.08 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (./graphics.cfg)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 82.
 (./dvips.def
File: dvips.def 1996/12/12 v3.0d Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)

Answer (score 4):

`(./graphics.cfg)`

you have a `graphics.cfg` file in the current directory that you may want to delete. Whatever is in it, it is doing the wrong thing.

You should also delete the local copies of `color.cfg`, `graphics.sty`, `graphicx.sty` `dvips.def` etc they are all ancient versions for example your log shows

```
trig 1994/10/16 v1.08 sin cos tan (DPC)
```

whereas the current version is

```
trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
```

Comment: Many thanks David, it has worked out! Just to precise my issue: the offending files were not a part of TexLive directories such as /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg etc. There are they all up to date. The offending files were all locally stored in the same directory as my tex source file. They were there apparently for many years without causing any problem till recently. Best wishes

Comment: @Alex yes that's what the `(./zzzz.sty)` in the log is telling you, that you have local copies masking the installed version. 1994 doesn't seem that long ago:) DPC.